# So is an [Email] attribute built in ASP.NET MVC 3 or not?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, attributes, data-annotations

The `[Email]` attribute was going to be built into ASP.NET MVC 3 as it was in futures? So is it now available or not? I guess it is quite a dumb question but I've spent some time googling and didn't find any normal answer.

The email regex:

```
"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$"
```

Comment: The compiler will tell you. If it compiles, it's built in.

Comment: it compiles but doesn't provide any client side validation

Comment: I'm astonished it compiles. What's the full namespace of the _EmailAttribute_ class? The attribute doesn't belong to MVC3 and it probably comes from a third party library using it for something completely different.

Comment: it is an attribute from ComponentModel.DataAnnotations , looks like this: [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email is wrong")]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `[Email]` is supposed to be a data annotation for MVC models (like `[Required]`), then it's not built into ASP.NET MVC 3.

All the model data annotations are found in the namesace *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations*. There you find classes like *RequiredAttribute*.

**Update:**

It's pretty easy to add the *Email* attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public EmailAttribute() : base("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What the best or correct regular expression for checking email addresses is, is a separate and long debate on the net. I'm not insisting that mine is either of it.

Comment: yeah.. I ended up doing it the same way. the regexp is. but the reason I was asking is that I wanted my code to be clean. and now I'm adding this attributes that are obvious.

Answer (score 26):

You can include System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and use

```
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public String ToAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: That'll be because DataType attributes don't actually provide any sort of validation out of the box, which is what the OP was after. DataType attribute change the way that the HtmlHelper methods render model properties in templates.

Answer (score 7):

`[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute]` turns out to validate email by regex (at least in 4.5)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this, http://dataannotationsextensions.org/.  It has both server side and client side validation capabilities.
It uses this regex underneath.

```
new Regex(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: @Chris Marisic, thanks for reivising this.  This is before time i used to care for using Markdown properly. hahaha.