# What is wrong with my model? [EmailAddress] namespace could not be found?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, models

I installed data annotations MVC3 (I am using MVC3) and my [EmailAddress] data annotation cannot be found. I searched online and I do not understand why it is not referencing.

Here is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

    namespace Projectx.Models
    {

        public class PreSignUpUser
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you include the full error message?

Comment: quasi duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841518/so-is-an-email-attribute-built-in-asp-mvc3-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
```

in place of

```
[EmailAddress]
```

Comment: Hi I did that and then I installed the DataAnnotations class from Nuget.

Comment: @Darren Glad it worked, but that should have shipped with MVC3, no?

Answer (score 1):

The data annotation you are looking for is actually [Email].

[EmailAddress] is not part of Data Annotations Extensions.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention I used [Email].

Answer (score 0):

For me these answers didn't work. I solved this by adding the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` nuget package, then adding the reference

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

if you haven't already done so.